# Send a critical alert to a different mail address in munin?

Tags: notifications, warnings, alert, munin

I'm using the resource monitoring tool Munin. (Version  1.4.6)

Today I've enabled the email alert function to receive a notification when a value is too high.

With munin it is possible to set two levels of alerting. (Warning or Critical)

I've configured the munin.conf file like this:

```
contact.scs.command mail -s "Munin notification ${var:host}" simon@domain.net

[varnish;server01.domain.net]
  address server01.domain.net
  use_node_name yes
  cpu.iowait.warning 14
  cpu.iowait.critical 17
  cpu.contacts scs
```

When a performance value exceeds the defined maximum, a mail notification with the alert will be successfully send. :-)

**Now to my Question:**

Would it be possible to send a critical notification to a different mail address than the warning notification?

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything at web.

I've already tried this, but it didn't work for me:

```
contact.scs.command mail -s "Munin notification ${var:host}" simon@domain.net
contact.crit.command mail -s "Munin notification ${var:host}" critical@domain.net

[varnish;server01.domain.net]
  address server01.domain.net
  use_node_name yes
  cpu.iowait.warning 14
  cpu.iowait.critical 17
  cpu.contacts scs
  cpu.contacts.warning scs
  cpu.contacts.critical crit
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Also looking for the same thing. I want warnings to go to my notification tab in gmail but I want criticals to go into the main tab.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately munin doesn't support this and its documentation is very poor. But it's possible to do it via workaround. My case below is little bit more complicated, I have to first ssh to another machine, since in my case mail cannot be sent directly from munin machine. But it's of course possible to simplify it without using ssh.

```
contact.email.command ssh user@10.20.30.40 "cat > /tmp/muninmail.txt; bash -c \"if grep -q CRITICAL /tmp/muninmail.txt; then cat /tmp/muninmail.txt | mail -s 'Munin-notification for ${var:group} :: ${var:host}' mail@domain.net; fi\"
```

Without ssh, something like this should do it, but I haven't tested this case:

```
contact.email.command bash -c "cat > /tmp/muninmail.txt; if grep -q CRITICAL /tmp/muninmail.txt; then cat /tmp/muninmail.txt | mail -s 'Munin-notification for ${var:group} :: ${var:host}' mail@domain.net; fi"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess for you. For all the warning-only contacts:

```
contact.scs.command mail -s "Munin notification ${var:host}" simon@domain.net
contact.scs.always_send warning
```

For all the critical-only contacts:

```
contact.crit.command mail -s "Munin notification ${var:host}" critical@domain.net
contact.crit.always_send critical
```

For any warning-and-critical contacts:

```
contact.other.command mail -s "Munin notification ${var:host}" other@domain.net
contact.other.always_send warning critical
```

Comment: Hi josephdpurcell,
The always_send command is for a different usage. That makes that munin always send messages even if the state didn't change since previous run. See also: http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/munin.conf What I need is something that controls the notification behaviour in general. Thank you anyway!